# Реализация изменения координат дуги при клике в canvas (или без)

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на li менялся радиус дуги, в зависимости от их расположения:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 100;
ctx.lineWidth = 1; // толщина линии
ctx.moveTo(11, 100); //передвигаем перо
ctx.lineTo(350, 100); //рисуем линию
ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
ctx.strokeStyle = "purple";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.lineWidth=100;
ctx.lineWidth= 1;
ctx.moveTo(11,100);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(26, 0, 50, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.ruler {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: url("sprite.webp") no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 67px;
    width: 877px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.ruler-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    padding-top: 270px;
}

.ruler-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
}

.ruler-list__item {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-left: -7px;
}

.double__numbers {
    margin-right: 24px;
}

.bold {
    /*margin-top: -4px;*/
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ruler-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 19px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

.ruler-axis {
    width: 813px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-left: 33px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.ruler-axis__item-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    background-color: #000000;
    top: -12px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.ruler-axis::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 2px;
    right: -4px;
    top: 6px;
    transform: rotate(-46deg);
    background-color: #000000;
}

.ruler-axis::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 2px;
    right: -4px;
    top: -6px;
    transform: rotate(46deg);
    background-color: #000000;
}

.double {
    margin-right: 34px;
}

input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.user-input {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 95px;
}

input[type='number'] {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 76px;
    font-size: 66px;
}

span {
    display: block;
}

#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 818px;
    height: 132px;
    margin-top: -79px;
}

.user-input span {
    font-size: 75px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.input__container {
    margin-left: 21px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<main class="main-class">
    <div class="ruler-container">
        <div class="user-input">
            <span class="user-input__number" id="input_number">7</span>
            <span class="user-input__sign">+</span>
            <span class="user-input__number" id="input_second_number">8</span>
            <span class="user-inupt__total">=</span>
            <span class="user-inupt__mockup">?</span>
            <div class="input__container hidden">
                <label for="result" class="input-container__label">
                    <input type="number" max="500" class="input-container__input-block" id="result">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ruler">
            <div class="ruler-axis">
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
                <div class="ruler-axis__item-block"></div>
            </div>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="818" height="132">
                Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
            <ul class="ruler-list">
                <li class="ruler-list__item bold">0</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item">1</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item">2</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item">3</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item">4</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item bold">5</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item">6</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item">7</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item">8</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item">9</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item bold double__numbers">10</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">11</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">12</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">13</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">14</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">15</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">16</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">17</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">18</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item double__numbers">19</li>
                <li class="ruler-list__item bold double__numbers">20</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- end snippet --

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Под линейку я хочу подложить линию также нарисованную в canvas, чтобы отметить на ней точки, в которые попадают li. Но хотелось бы попробовать и другие способы:

1. Возможно ли  как -то сопоставить координаты li из html (чтобы не рисовать дополнительную линию в canvas) чтобы при клике в canvas стрелка по ним перемещалась? Как это можно реализовать?(насколько я поняла, способ это не очень хороший)
2. Возможно ли вообще обойтись без canvas и как-то использовать js анимации?